# Unattended upgrades

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

There are 2 files with same configuration settings in unattended 
upgrades `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`:

`20auto-upgrades` and `10periodic`.

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

1. What is the difference?
2. For `AutoCleanInterval` to work, do I need to set the following option in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

   ```
   Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";
   ```

**Update:**
Not sure if the options are working. In the following test, unattended is very fast compared to apt update. I don't know why:

```
abhishek ~ $ time sudo unattended-upgrade -v
[sudo] password for abhishek: 
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Initial whitelisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-proposed', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports']
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals

real    0m5.108s
user    0m2.840s
sys     0m0.040s
```

Normal update

```
abhishek ~ $ time sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Err:4 https://tiliado.eu/nuvolaplayer/repository/deb xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve host: tiliado.eu
Hit:5 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                    
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/anoise/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnumdk/lollypop/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwendal-lebihan-dev/hexchat-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:15 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./ InRelease 
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mehanik/ksuperkey/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:22 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./ Release               
Hit:24 http://apt.nylas.com/ubuntu vivid InRelease
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:27 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'repository.spotify.com' [IP: 54.235.176.26 80]
Err:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tuxonice/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 54.235.176.26 80]
Err:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 54.235.176.26 80]
Err:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 54.235.176.26 80]
Fetched 94.5 kB in 3min 47s (415 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'repository.spotify.com' [IP: 54.235.176.26 80]
W: Failed to fetch https://tiliado.eu/nuvolaplayer/repository/deb/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve host: tiliado.eu
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tuxonice/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 54.235.176.26 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 54.235.176.26 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 54.235.176.26 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

real    3m51.729s
user    0m4.140s
sys     0m0.764s
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

- No difference between the contents, only that `10periodic` will be parsed earlier than `20auto-upgrades` due to the ascending parsing behavior of `apt`. If same directive is mentioned in two different files (or more), the the earlier one(s) will be overridden by the last one.
- No.

  `APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval` takes an integer value and sets the interval for the removal of the locally cached packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial`, so it is analogous to `sudo apt-get clean`.

  On the other hand, `Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies` takes boolean and is analogous to the command `sudo apt-get autoremove` i.e. will remove all dependencies that are not being used by any of the installed packages.

---

To enable `Unattended-Upgrade`, you need to have the directive:

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade
```

defined in any file comes before the `Unattened-Upgrade` definitions (e.g. definitions usually put in `/etc/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`).

The example values are:

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1"; ## Runs "Unattened-Upgrade" daily
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "7"; ## Runs weekly
```

As for when `apt` runs this (and others), it is run daily, and the operations are defined in the `/etc/cron.daily/apt` file.

On my system, the `cron` files on `/etc/cron.daily/` are started running at 06:26 AM:

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

Comment: Thanks!! If you set conflicting options in `10periodic` and `20auto-upgrades` which one will prevail?

Comment: What is the interval for `Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies`? I ask this as there is no corresponding `APT::Periodic::` to it.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Check my edits..

Comment: Thanks! I think you missed my 2nd comment, does that make sense? So ideally changes should be made in `20auto-upgrades`?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Check my edits..

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Don't forget to mark it as accepted so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Comment: Thanks, again!! I don't have any `/etc/cron.daily/` which confuses me what is running. I tried a test, please check the update in the question.